# C# int.ParseInt() performance issue

Tags: c#, performance

I recently discovered something strange, what I absolutely can't explain.

My current project is pretty slow due to multiple interleaved loops in a recursion performing permissionwriting and -reading to/from the filsystem. As I analyzed the diagnostic tool, I saw, that cpu load is a bit higher as it should. The details showed, that a parseInt-call is taking over 30% of total workload.

What could be interesting to know, too: This specific parse was there to throw an exception most of the time.

I don't think, that this parse-method is supposed to take that much power. Can somebody maybe explain this behavior?

With ParseInt
[image: [With ParseInt]

Without ParseInt
[image: [Without ParseInt]

P.S. Sorry for this pictures being no screenshot

Comment: So how about parsing things without exceptions, then? That's what `TryParse` is for. Even better, if you've identified this operation as a bottleneck, how about removing it entirely? Any chance you're reading something as a string when you could be reading it directly in a typed way?

Comment: Exceptions should be thrown when something _exceptional_ happens—not as a matter of course.  If you want to test whether a string represents a number, use `int.TryParse`.  Note that text processing is generally slow, and without knowing more about your program, I couldn’t say whether it’s the parsing or the exception handling that’s causing your CPU to spike.

Comment: I removed it by the time I discovered this. But i didn't know that is that expensive to throw an exception. I just found it to be interesting. Me and a friend (both beginners) were riddling a lot about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if ParseInt is throwing exceptions, the performance degradation is understandable, it is in general expensive to create and throw an exception and even if you catch it and ignore it, doing that in a recursive loop can impact performances if it happens many times.

Comment: That being said, Exceptions are not a comfy way for error logging. Throwing/catching exceptions should be 'exceptional', i.e. something happens, what should not happen normaly.

Answer (score 3):

If your `Parse` method throws an exception it can be cause of performance impact.

From [Exceptions and Performance MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exceptions-and-performance):

> One common concern related to exceptions is that if exceptions are used for code that routinely fails, the performance of the implementation will be unacceptable. This is a valid concern. When a member throws an exception, its performance can be orders of magnitude slower.